# How to call parameters from an API (json) in html

Tags: html, json, api, parameters

I have created [my own API](https://sheetsu.com/apis/f924526c), and would like to know how could I call the parameters?
I have been trying to call the "type" parameter with the following code but it's being undefined... And nothing shows up in the console even when I am only logging "json"...

Can some one please tell me where did I do wrong please?

Thanks a lot!!! :))) xxx

```html
  <canvas id="myCanvas"> </canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

   $(document).ready(function(){  

   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

   ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var url = "https://sheetsu.com/apis/f924526c"; 


   $.getJSON(url,function(json){
   
                                console.log(json);

    var type = json.type;
    $('type').append(type);
    console.log(type);

   });
  });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at a part of the JSON data you got from the server:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "success": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "number": "0",
      "URL random digit1": "1",
      "URL random digit2": "8",
      "id": "1a8",
      "name": "user1",
      "type": "mf",
      "url": "http://test.com/customised_url_1a8",
      "message": "bonjour user1"
    },
....
```

According to this, you should access the 0th element's "type" in the following manner:

```
json.result[0].type
```

Please note than your json is converted to a JS object upon reception. You should follow the object's scheme to access any property of it.

Comment: Hi Charlie, thank you very much for your reply.
I tried to change it like this, but there is still nothing coming out from the console...
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){

    var type = json.result[0].type;
    $('type').append(type);
    console.log(type);

   });

Comment: Please create a fiddle. Then I can see why. Please note that you don't need to have a canvas in the fiddle. Just include only the relevant code and make sure it works up to the point we discuss here.

Comment: Your problem is in this line: `$('type').append(type);`. The console shows the type if you remove this line. Please follow a JQuery tutorial to find out the proper use of `$` function.